# Unknown table in field list even though table definitely exists

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 3 tables together but I keep getting 'unknown table 'calls' in field list.  I know the table 'calls' exists

This works...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calls WHERE id = '$diary_id'";
```

but this doesn't...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT calls.id AS calls_id, calls.assigned_user_id AS assigned_user) calls
RIGHT JOIN accounts on accounts.parent_id = accounts.id
LEFT JOIN users on assigned_user = user.id
WHERE calls_id = '$diary_id'";
```

I am trying to use aliases because the tables I am trying to join have the same field names (an inherited database I have to use).

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your subquery:

```
SELECT calls.id AS calls_id, calls.assigned_user_id AS assigned_user
```

is selecting `calls.id` and `calls.assigned_user` but there is no `FROM` clause from which the `calls` table/alias is defined.  Add `FROM calls` to the subquery (although why use a subquery here at all?).

You're also referring to `user.id` in your join criterion, but the table is called `users`.

And your join criterion for the accounts table, `accounts.parent_id = accounts.id`, looks very suspect: it appears that you're trying to traverse hierarchical data that has been stored using the adjacency list model, but this join won't accomplish that; indeed, MySQL doesn't support recursive functions—so it is not well suited to this model at all.  You might consider restructuring your data to use either nested sets or closure tables.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041) for more information.

Instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   calls
  RIGHT JOIN accounts ON accounts.parent_id  = accounts.id -- is this right?
   LEFT JOIN users    ON calls.assigned_user = user.id
WHERE calls.id = '$diary_id'
```

Comment: you're correct when yu say accounts.parent_id looks a bit dodgy, it should be calls.parent_id = account.id.  I'd been looking at this for several hours and had rewritten it many times because I was missing the from clause, doh